# What color are Arwen's eyes?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

In the non-canonical LOTR Wikia page, it lists Arwen's eye color as "grey". But I distinctly remember in the film her eyes being a piercing blue, most notably when she is crying after Elrond is describing how she will live long after Aaragorn is dead and there will be nothing left for her except sorrow. If anyone can find a screenshot of her eyes on that scene, please add it (I can't find one).

Were her eyes different colors in the movies? Were they different vs JRRT's writings?

Comment: They look [pretty darned blue](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/seigneur-des-anneaux/images/f/f9/Arwen2.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140329102507&path-prefix=fr) to me

Comment: @Richard - I've seen that one, but I'm looking for the specific scene in Rivendell where she is shedding a couple of years after her father explains how lonely she will be.

Comment: They're blue in [that scene](http://cdn4.teen.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/lord-of-the-rings-arwen-sad.gif) too, and the [flashback sequence](http://www-static.weddingbee.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/04/14/z141036.jpg)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the Fellowship of the Ring ("*Many Meetings*"), her eyes were described as grey:

> In the middle of the table, against the woven cloths upon the wall,
>   there was a chair under a canopy, and there sat a lady fair to look
>   upon, and so like was she in form of womanhood to Elrond that Frodo
>   guessed that she was one of his close kindred. Young she was and yet
>   not so. The braids of her dark hair were touched by no frost, her
>   white arms and clear face were flawless and smooth, **and the light of
>   stars was in her bright eyes, grey as a cloudless night;** yet queenly
>   she looked, and thought and knowledge were in her glance, as of one
>   who has known many things that the years bring.

Interestingly, despite the fact the Liv Tyler's eyes are [naturally blue](http://cache4.asset-cache.net/gc/168933988-actress-liv-tyler-attends-a-photocall-for-gettyimages.jpg?v=1&c=IWSAsset&k=2&d=GkZZ8bf5zL1ZiijUmxa7Qdb0hZsCWzTlZwiwIvBQae70EIIMYaSpm4SpSXPrYNuEEhQcAzfc00538meDuj6teA%3D%3D), in some film scenes she wore [tinted lenses](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Xi6SCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA174&lpg=PA174&dq=liv%20tyler%20%22contact%20lenses%22&source=bl&ots=SEk9YqIkeD&sig=fomVsFNExlXEI6e3zhjJwBRJ3Sk&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=liv%20tyler%20%22contact%20lenses%22&f=false), presumably to accentuate the colour for the cameras.

[image]

Comment: So it sounds like the movie (blue eyes) diverged from the book (grey eyes). I thought I saw green eyes somewhere, but that could just be my imagination—or my penchant for green eyed elves.

Comment: Pale blue eyes can look gray in certain lighting. That passage doesn't completely exclude the possibility that her eyes sometimes look blue. (Just pointing that out—not disagreeing.)

Comment: A cloudless night is grey? What? I'm really not sure what picture Tolkien is trying to pain there. When I think of a cloudless night, I think of a dark sky with points of light glittering all over. There's nothing "grey" about what I picture; is Tolkein trying to evoke some image that's not coming to my mind?

Comment: The _landscape_ is grey at night when lit by stars and moon.